# Как изменить текста кнопки "В корзину" на "В корзине"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Только начинаю разбираться во Vue.

Подскажите, как сделать изменение текста кнопки "В корзину", на "В корзине".

Если есть какие то неверные подходы, то ткните меня носом (желательно с комментарием, почему не верно).
Можно ссылкой на доку, но лучше своими словами постарайтесь объяснить)

Пример кода в песочнице.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-moser-kww6r?file=/src/App.vue

Так же можете подлиться хорошими ресурсами и видеоуроками, для начально изучения Vue. (Желательно русскоязычными)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код принято размещать в вопросе (не по ссылке), конечно желательно чтобы он был минимальным (без посторонних операций). Задача, если она о выводе в шаблоне, решается директивой `v-if`, либо `{{ инлайн-интерполяцией }}`, либо vue-фильтрами - см. оф. документацию Vue (хороший ресурс).

Comment: как я понял, у карточки товара текст "в корзинУ", автору надо чтобы после клика на нее текст поменялся на "в корзинЕ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходи в файл компонента и там прямо меняй текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советую посмотреть Владилен Минин на ютубе. Очень легко его слушать и отлично подает материал. Вначале возможно не все понятно будет, но в голове все равно основные моменты отложатся.

Comment: Я думаю напрасно недооценивают Минина, он зрит в корень - отредактируй файл и готово! Зачем заморочки с состояниями и прочей ерундой.

Comment: Плюсик - но честно, очень жутко становится от таких вoпросов-ответов (если новых программистов надо учить открывать файлик и менять в нем одну буковку... и об этом снимают видео... то это уже точка невозврата).

Comment: Если задать тут сложный вопрос, то скорее всего ответа не получишь вообще.